# Passing an instance to a class used with registerclassmap

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I use `registerclassmap` to map values with CSVReader, like below:

```
AppSettings settings;
...
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EmployeeMapping>();
```

How to pass the settings instance to use it in the `EmployeeMappaing` instance created by CSVReader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to do something like this?  You can create the `EmployeeMapping` instance yourself rather than have `RegisterClassMap` create the instance.

```cs
AppSettings settings;
...
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new EmployeeMapping(settings));
```